# Input and two buttons side by side in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I got an input and two icons (that work like buttons) and I want them to be side by side in a table. 
Besides, when on click of the icons ("buttons"), I want it to get me the value of the input.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {
  alert($("#add").closest());
});
```

```css
.w3-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#quantidade input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40px;
}

#quantidade div {
  font-size: 15pt;
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#quantidade i {
  padding: 0 3px;
}

#quantidade i:hover {
  background-color: #0F292F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#quantidade {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

table {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table class="w3-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        <h2>Lista das Compras</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Arroz</td>
      <td id='quantidade' class='w3-right'>
        <input type='text' class='w3-input w3-left' value='1'>
        <div>
          <i id='add' class='fa fa-angle-up'></i>
          <i id='rem' class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KukApep3/8qn7mLj3/1/)

Comment: Why wrap buttons in `<div>` which is a block level element if you want it to be inline?

Comment: Ug, tables are for displaying tabular data, not for layout.

Comment: @charlietfl, I wanted the <input> and <div> inline, but the <i> block

Comment: @j08691, this is just a bit of what I'm doing, I know that tables are for displaying tabular data and that is what this one is for

Comment: It is better to use the HTML markup to describe what something _**is**_, so using a `<button>` element enclosing your `<i ... class=...>` would be semantically better.  The fact that you want a particular icon on your button is a _presentation_ decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
  alert($("#add").closest('td').prev().find('input[type=text]').val());
});
```

```css
.w3-table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}

#quantidade input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40px;
}
#quantidade div {
  font-size: 15pt;
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#quantidade i {padding: 0 3px;}
#quantidade i:hover {
  background-color: #0F292F;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#quantidade {padding-left: 80px;}

table {width: 40%;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="w3-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"><h2>Lista das Compras</h2></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Arroz</td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='button1' value='1'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <span id='add' class='fa fa-angle-up'></span><br>
          <span id='rem' class='fa fa-angle-down'></span>
         </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've change the table after an answer ( https://jsfiddle.net/KukApep3/8qn7mLj3/2/ ), and with your exemple it alerts "undefined"

Comment: @MarianaLeites, I have updated my answer with you latest `table`. Please have look...thanks.

Comment: I actually put it to work, and I did exactly what you did, this was what I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <tr>
    <td>Arroz</td>
    <td id='quantidade'>
      <input type='text' id='button1' value='1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id='add' class='fa fa-angle-up'></span><br>
        <span id='rem' class='fa fa-angle-down'></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
    alert($("#button1").val());
});
```

Comment: The table part worked pretty well, thanks ;)
But the jquery no. When I click the button, I need to get the value of the closest input of the button I clicked, but no matter what I do, it just alerts "undefined"

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find('input').val());
});

$(document).on("click", "#rem", function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find('input').val());
});

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery code

```
 $(document).on("click", "#add", function () {
        alert($(this).parent().closest('div').prev('input').val());
    });
```

As you said you have changed your table structure like this

```
<table class="w3-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="3"><h2>Lista das Compras</h2></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Arroz</td>
                <td>
                  <input type='text' id='button1' value='1'>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div>
                    <span id='add' class='fa fa-angle-up'></span><br>
                    <span id='rem' class='fa fa-angle-down'></span>
                   </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

So code for new structure table will be

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function () {
            alert($(this).parent().closest('div').parent().prev('td').find('#button1').val());
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I click the button, I need to get the value of the closest input of the button I clicked, but no matter what I do, it just alerts "undefined"

Comment: I suggest you should explain your question clearly. You said `I want it to get me the value of the input.` never said that you want the value of closest input. By the way check my update.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was a bit clear with the jquery. And it is still "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

It works with this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find('input').val());
});
```